# How to search azure table storage JSON response in logic app?

Tags: json, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am getting the below response from azure table storage. I need to search the response using the GeneralId and get the response true or false wheather an entity is available in table or not.

```
{
  "odata.metadata": "https://google.net/$metadata#GetStudents",
  "value": [
    {
      "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-05-01T18%3A04%3A37.5904256Z'\"",
      "PartitionKey": "mypartitionkey",
      "RowKey": "myrowkey",
      "Timestamp": "",
      "GeneralId": "456265d8-6c3b-11e9-a923-1681be663d3e",
      "Inc": "PIR165461",
      "Name": "",
      "StudentId": "c17a3c42-6c48-11e9-a923-1681be663d3e",
      "Subject": ""
    },
    {
      "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-04-30T16%3A49%3A10.0746254Z'\"",
      "PartitionKey": "par1",
      "RowKey": "row1",
      "Timestamp": "2019-04-30T16:49:10.0746254Z",
      "Generald": "fada7dd0-6c48-11e9-a923-1681be663d3e",
      "Inc": "PIR4237341",
      "Name": "",
      "StudentId": "c70c5de9-ac8d-4432-9f3c-1f8bede83504",
      "Subject": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to check if one entity exists in the table. So you could get the partition and row value from the json to check. Below is the workflow.

[image]

After Get Entities values, add a `For each` action, in the Input choose Dynamic content `Get entities result List of Entities`.

Then add `Condition` action to judge if the entity you want in the table. Use two condition, one is partition the other one is row vale.

[image]

After this you could add actions under If true or If false. And here is my test result.

[image]